# how can i inform other users about new user registration?

Tags: users, email, user-registration, account

I try to inform other users about new user registration in wordpress but I did not succeed. please help me

I use ultimate member and user pro plugin.

Comment: please see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `user_register` hook and then mail all your subscribers.
Something like:

```
add_action('user_register','notify_new_member');

function notify_new_member(){
  global $wpdb;
  $usersarray = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_email FROM $wpdb->users;");    
  $users = implode(",", $usersarray);
  mail($users, "New Member", 'A new member has just joined.');
}
```

Comment: but this code is not work :(

Comment: In case you didn't understand, the code should be added to your theme's functions.php file. When you say it doesn't work, what did you try and how did you test?